# Update nested resource through API/Json

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, api, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm building an API endpoint to update a model. i can update every column except nested resources, I've tried different approachs but nothing seems to work

This is the JSON i'm trying to send to the server

```
{
"reservation": {
    "reservation_dates": [
        {
            "is_desirable": true,
            "date": "5-10-2019"
        }
         ]
  }
}
```

I'm getting a unpermitted_param from reservation_date although i've added it to my

```
def permitted_attributes_for_update
params.require(:reservation).permit(:date, :time, :comment, :budget, :currency, :status,
                                    :general_text, :idea_text, :artist_text, :desired_city,
                                    :desired_country, :desired_googleid, :studio_id, :artist_id,
                                    :tattoos, reservation_dates: [], general_url_array: [],idea_url_array: [],
                                    artist_url_array: [])
end
```

I want to either be able to update directly from the JSON or at least permit the array so I can use later on my UpdateService

Thanks for any help

[edit: this is the error I'm getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ng8HQ.png)

Comment: Update the question with the exact error.

Comment: Have you allowed nested attributes in the model?

Comment: I have @8bithero

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify what is permitted in `reservation_dates`:

`params.require(:reservation).permit(reservation_dates_attributes: [:is_desirable, : date], ...)`

However, be careful that if your `reservation` has_many `reservation_dates`, then this will cause conflicts: reservation_dates are supposed to be instances of `ReservationDate` but you are providing hashes. The rails' way is to use `reservation_dates_attributes` instead of `reservation_dates`.

Comment: i've tried that. without it, it updated the other non-nested fields. if i add those symbols to my permit it breaks the whole thing

Comment: See the update, `it breaks the whole thing` means the parameters managed to get permission, but its presence caused conflicts.

Comment: now i get "unpermitted paramiter: :reservation_dates_attributes"

Comment: i've had accepts_nested_attributes_for :reservation_dates to my reservation model and tried both :reservation_dates and :reservation_dates_attributes to my .permit()

Comment: params permit needs to be updated as well: zparams.require(:reservation).permit(reservation_dates_attributes: [:is_desirable, : date], ...)`

Comment: i don't need to update automatically if that's not possible. i need at least to permit the array of hashes to go through

Comment: i got the array to go through :D thanks. now i'll develop some logic to update the nested models

Comment: what doesn't make sense? i have a reservation that has many dates. the preference is the joint table with the is_desirable column.

i need some logic to create new/update other preferences+dates "combo"